# SwiftUI StoreKit 2 - how to cancel a subscription using SubscriptionStoreView on MacOS?

Tags: xcode, macos, swiftui, storekit

Goal: cancel a subscription using SubscriptionStoreView.
Problems:
1- .manageSubscriptionsSheet modifier is available only in UIKit, not MacOS.

2- SubscriptionStoreView doesn't have a button to cancel subscription.

Question: How can a user cancel the subscription using SubscriptionStoreView (not Apple Store)?

```
   import SwiftUI
    import StoreKit
    
    struct ContentView: View {
        @State private var paywallShown = false
        @State private var presentingSubscriptionSheet = false
    
        var body: some View {
            Button {
                self.presentingSubscriptionSheet = true
            } label: {
                Text("Show subscriptionManager")
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $paywallShown) {
                SubscriptionStoreView(groupID: "21438756"
            }
    
            // Apply this to iOS only
            #if os(iOS)
            .manageSubscriptionsSheet(
                isPresented: $presentingSubscriptionSheet,
                subscriptionGroupID: "21438486"
            )
            #endif
```